# How to join a "IN" result and check "where" active = 1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

In my query I check if `tokens.id` exists in `dapp_tokens`. I want to add that the result in `dapp_tokens` also has to be `active = 1` in the `dapps` table.

So I need to join the `dapps` table of the row with `tokens.id` that has been found in `dapp_tokens`, but how can I do that in Raw SQL?

```
$data['tokens'] = Token::where('active', 1)
    ->whereRaw('tokens.id in (select token_id from dapp_tokens where active = ?)', [1])
    ->sortable('market_cap')
    ->orderby('id','desc')
    ->paginate($page_count);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? That code does not look like raw SQL after all

Comment: whereRaw is Raw SQL in Laravel, i tried to make a leftjoin but that doesn't seem to work or I did it wrong in context to the current code. It would also work with Laravel SQL syntax i guess, but my thought was to use RAW code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, but i'm only allowed to get 1 col value with "IN":

> Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
        $data['tokens'] = Token::where('tokens.active', 1)
            ->whereRaw('tokens.id in (select token_id, dapp_id from dapp_tokens LEFT JOIN dapps ON dapps.id = dapp_id where dapps.active = ?)', [1])
            ->sortable('market_cap')->orderby('id','desc')->paginate($page_count);
```

Edit: seems like I had the solution already, just had to delete dapp_id from the selector in the whereRaw